# Como extraer solo un dato de un jsonArrayRequest en android (Java)

Tags: java, android-studio

Este es el método para mostrar todos los datos el id que se le envia se extrae de un EditText, lo que quiero es extraer el dato nombre de un JsonArray ya probe varios metodos y no logro traerlo, con el metodo mostrado se trae los datos que corresponden al id
Este es el Json

```json
[{"id":1,"nombre":"Victoria","descripcion":"Obscura 455ml","precio":"28","provedor_id":"5"},{"id":5,"nombre":"Indio","descripcion":"Obscura 355ml","precio":"25","provedor_id":"2"},{"id":6,"nombre":"Tecate","descripcion":"Obscura 455ml","precio":"28","provedor_id":"5"},{"id":7,"nombre":"Corona","descripcion":"Clara 230ml","precio":"20","provedor_id":"2"},{"id":8,"nombre":"Ultra","descripcion":"Clara 525ml","precio":"27","provedor_id":"4"}]
```

```java
public void MostrarArray(){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    final String url = "http://10.0.0.12/ProyectoFinal/public/api/cervezas/"+id;
    // prepare the Request
    JsonArrayRequest getRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            // display response
                Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                tvMostar.setText(response.toString());
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
            }
        }
    );
                
    // add it to the RequestQueue
    queue.add(getRequest);
}
```

Comment: ¿Has probado con Android Volley? Te invito a tomar una revisión de esto: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request

Comment: Esa es la libreria que uso.. el problema es que no se como extraer ejemplo el campo nombre del json

Comment: Debes asegurarte de usar la versión más actual de Android Volley y configurala en tu archivo build.gradle, esta versión tiene la clase JsonObjectResquest que te puede ayudar, por ejemplo:

dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    ...
}

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo tener el json asi:

```
 {
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "nombre":"Victoria",
         "descripcion":"Obscura 455ml",
         "precio":"28",
         "provedor_id":"5"
      },
      {
         "id":5,
         "nombre":"Indio",
         "descripcion":"Obscura 355ml",
         "precio":"25",
         "provedor_id":"2"
      },
      {
         "id":6,
         "nombre":"Tecate",
         "descripcion":"Obscura 455ml",
         "precio":"28",
         "provedor_id":"5"
      },
      {
         "id":7,
         "nombre":"Corona",
         "descripcion":"Clara 230ml",
         "precio":"20",
         "provedor_id":"2"
      },
      {
         "id":8,
         "nombre":"Ultra",
         "descripcion":"Clara 525ml",
         "precio":"27",
         "provedor_id":"4"
      }
   ]
}
```

De esta manera, el JSON está compuesto de una clave llamada data, seguida de un Array, y dentro de ese array están los elementos por separado. En esa estructura, para llegar a nombre, tendrías entonces que hacer algo así:

```
JSONArray data=response.getJSONArray("data");
JSONObject firstJSON=data[0];
String strCharacter=firstJSON.getString("nombre");  
miTextView.setText(strCharacter);
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Te sirvió o no es lo que esperabas? dilo con confianza, así crecemos todos en esta comunidad.

Comment: No me funciono .. pero es por que ya cambie mi jsonarray a un jsonobject pero sigo en las mismas .. jaja pero agradezco tu respuesta

Comment: De echo ya postee una pregunta con el codigo bien.